How to write the full path of a file?
I want to write down the full path of the files from My Drive in Google Sheets. I am using the following code:
var files=DriveApp.searchFiles("'me' in owners");
while (files.hasNext()){
  var file=files.next();
  if (file.getParents().hasNext()){
    var parents=file.getParents().next();
  }
  else {var parents='No parents';}
}

This code returns the immediate parent folder/location of the file. For example, if file X is located in the path:
My Drive/Folder 1/Folder 2/ Folder 3/Folder 4
the code returns only:
Folder 4
But I want it to return all the path.
Does anyone have any idea of how to resolve this issue?

Get the Full path of the files from Drive
A possible reason why your code does not work as intended is that it only retrieves the first parent folder of each file. It captures just "Folder 4" but doesn't go up the hierarchy to build the complete path.
To get the full path, you can try this:
function find() {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("'me' in owners");
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var path = [file.getName()]; 
    var current = file;
    
    while (current.getParents().hasNext()) {
      var parent = current.getParents().next();
      path.unshift(parent.getName()); 
      current = parent; 
    }
    
    console.log("Full path: " + path.join(' / ')); 
  }
}

If you need to find the full path of a specific file you can change the sample in the code below:
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("title: 'sample'");

REFERENCE:
While loop

Thanks, let me try it!

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
